# How to extract numbers from a text file

Tags: java, string, text, int

I have a text file that looks like:

```
1/1/2009    76.0    81.1    68.1    86.7    99.2    97.5    92.9
```

What I don't understand is how to pull out just the 7 numbers and not the date.

EDITcode so far:

When i run it nothing is printed?

```
File inputFile = new File ("C:/Users/Phillip/Documents/Temp/temperatures.txt .txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);


  while (scan.hasNextLine())
  {
  String line = scan.nextLine(); 

  String[] words = line.split(" "); 

  for (int index = 1; index < words.length; index++)
   System.out.println(words[index]);
```

Comment: Maybe split by spaces and iterate through the array?  Or a regular expression?

Comment: You should not repost the question but instead follow up on the clues that you've already been given :)

Comment: You already got a lot of help in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941542/how-to-use-a-for-loop-to-help-calculate-the-average-from-a-text-file/19941644#19941644) here. You need to do some work on your own. This is extremely basic stuff you are asking and it is better that you figure it out on your own, or you're not going to understand Java programming at all.

Comment: well i needed more help and you weren't going to give it. i was still lost can you look at what i got so far

Comment: @user2985204 There really isn't much more help to give you other than writing your assignment out for you. You're pretty close with what you have so far.

Comment: all i wanted was: you need to use this to find this to do this. what you gave me was hey go look here and it wasnt explained well enough for me.

Comment: @user2985204 I asked you to look at the String API which *easily* explains what you have to do. I'm sorry but if you can't figure it out from the explanation I've given you, then you aren't trying hard enough. You're literally asking people to tell you how to do *every step* of the program. MadProgrammer even gave you an example and you're telling him that it doesn't work and that you *need* it to be from a file. So far, what have you done on your own? Either way I wish you good luck with your programming adventures, but it is going to be very difficult this way.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `String#split` to split the values into seperate elements...

```
String text = "1/1/2009 76.0 81.1 68.1 86.7 99.2 97.5 92.9";
String[] parts = text.split(" ");
// You can now skip over the first element and process the remaining elements...
for (int index = 1; index < parts.length; index++) {
    // Convert the values as required...
}
```

You should also check out the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [Strings trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) for more details

Comment: This is a homework question from the OP; please don't give him the answer directly.

Comment: i keep getting an error on the text.split

Comment: @user2985204 Works fine for me.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Had I known it was a double post, I would not have answered at all.

Comment: i cant have string text = "1/1/2009 76.0 81.1 68.1 86.7 99.2 97.5 92.9";       i need it to be read from the text file

Comment: @MadProgrammer No worries. :)

Comment: why cant i just have help instead of ridiculing me for making a second post because i have been stuck for hours?

Comment: @user2985204 So try and make a leap from concept to implementation, change what I've provided with what you've read from the file.  No answer is ever likely to meet your needs 100%, you're going to have to adapt it.  Once you have read the next line from you file, apply the concept I've suggested...How do you get a `String` line from a `Scanner`?

Comment: We're not ridiculing you, we're trying to help you help yourself.  Spoon feeding you answer won't help make you a better program.  Making you think and establish the connections between idea and implementation will - This is what programing is all about...

Comment: can you give me somewhere i can read more about this then? im still struggling to see what i need to put in and my book isnt helping

Comment: @user2985204 There are two links at the bottom of the question and you could try taking a look at [Scanning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html), start by getting the file reading to work and dumping each line as a whole...

Comment: ok i have figured out the issues but now when i run it nothing is printed

Answer (score 0):

Use the String split method with a space separatpr. You'll get an array of 8 strings, your numbers are from index 1 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = "1/1/2009 76.0 81.1 68.1 86.7 99.2 97.5 92.9";

String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

will split the line into an array of words between the spaces. then skip the [0] index so:

```
for(int i = 1; i < words.length; i++)
    System.out.println(words[i]);
```

will print only the numbers

Comment: i get an error cannot find symbol for : String[] words = line.split(" ");

Comment: `words[1]`?  Also, this will only get the first 6 numbers...besides, didn't I just say this?

Comment: i dont know what it will get until i can fix the error

Comment: the 1 was a typo and while I was writing the solution, you posted yours so I didnt see it. This will not only get the first 6, it starts at index 1 not 0

Comment: my solution assumes you have a String variable called line which has the line you have in your question so String line = "1/1blabla";

Comment: `1` to `length - 1` will only get the first 6 numbers...

Comment: what do i put insted of line on the line.split i keep getting an error

Comment: I edited it so that you wont have errors. My apologies @MadProgrammer I think I need to go to bed lol.

Comment: My solution is exactly like @MadProgrammer OP, just has the print so I am going to remove it.

Comment: @MitchDart Ahh, sleep, how I miss you :P

Comment: when i run it nothing is printed

Answer (score 0):

First remove the leading input, then use a foreach loop over the result of a split on whitespace.

All that can be done in one line of code:

```
for (String number : line.replaceAll("^\\S+\\s+", "").split("\\s+")) {
    // do something with "number"
}
```